# Run a loop that have 3 steps for a query automation

Tags: python

I am trying to come up with a code that runs a query that has two different inputs, slices that query and pastes the data to the respective country sheet and tab name

```
ancestor_l = [1,2]
country_l = ['hk','my']
tab_name = ['sh1','sh2']
```

I want it to create a loop that prints the following output:

> ancestor 1 
>  opening hksh1 
>  pasting ancestor 1 to hksh1 
>  opening
>   mysh1 
>  pasting ancestor 1 to mysh1
>
> ancestor 2 
>  openig hksh2 
>  pasting ancestor 2 to hksh2 
>   opening mysh2 
>  pasting ancestor 2 to mysh2

my code looks like this

```
for anc in ancestor_l:
    print "\n"
    print "ancestor "+ str(anc)
    for tab in tab_name:
        for country in country_l:
            print "opening " + str(country) + str(tab)
            print "pasting ancestor "+str(anc)+" to "+ str(country) + str(tab)
```

but this outputs the following:

```
ancestor 1
opening hksh1
pasting ancestor 1 to hksh1
opening mysh1
pasting ancestor 1 to mysh1
opening hksh2
pasting ancestor 1 to hksh2
opening mysh2
pasting ancestor 1 to mysh2


ancestor 2
opening hksh1
pasting ancestor 2 to hksh1
opening mysh1
pasting ancestor 2 to mysh1
opening hksh2
pasting ancestor 2 to hksh2
opening mysh2
pasting ancestor 2 to mysh2
```

how do you fix the nested loop?

Comment: So you don't actually *want* the full Cartesian product? Then you don't want three nested loops. It looks like you want to `zip` up both `employee_l` and `country_l`, which have a 1-to-1 relationship.

Comment: Yep..... and also consider using str.format() for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example on how you can improve this (using zip as suggested by jonrsharpe):

```
ancestor_l = [1,2] 
country_l = ['hk','my'] 
tab_name = ['sh1','sh2'] 

for anc, tab in zip(ancestor_l,tab_name): 
    print("\nancestor {}".format(anc))
    for country in country_l:
        print("opening {}{}".format(country,tab))
        print("pasting ancestor {} to {}{}".format(anc,country,tab))
```

Output:

```
ancestor 1
opening hksh1
pasting ancestor 1 to hksh1
opening mysh1
pasting ancestor 1 to mysh1

ancestor 2
opening hksh2
pasting ancestor 2 to hksh2
opening mysh2
pasting ancestor 2 to mysh2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
tab_name_index = 0
for ancestor_l_val in ancestor_l:
    print "\n" 
    print "ancestor "+ str(ancestor_l_val)
    for country_l_val in country_l:
        print "opening "+str(country_l_val)+str(tab_name[tab_name_index])
        print "pasting ancestor "+ str(ancestor_l_val)+" to "+str(country_l_val)+str(tab_name[tab_name_index])
    tab_name_index +=1
```

Output

```
ancestor 1
opening hksh1
pasting ancestor 1 to hksh1
opening mysh1
pasting ancestor 1 to mysh1


ancestor 2
opening hksh2
pasting ancestor 2 to hksh2
opening mysh2
pasting ancestor 2 to mysh2
```